# Table view cell size for horizontal UICollectionView within a UITableView

Tags: uitableview, ios8, uicollectionview

I have set up multiple horizontally-scrolling `UICollectionView`(s), within a `UITableView`, so I can scroll vertically.

One issue I ran into is that, the row's height for the table view, is called before I know how tall they should be (I want the whole height of each `UICollectionView` to fill the table view cell).

How do I go about solving this?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to create a custom layout for the collection view. Then it could compute the cell size and be notified when the collection view is resized.

Comment: How does that get relayed to table view? Can you provide more details (i.e. code examples)?

Answer (score 1):

Using this function you can determine the height of the `collectionView` you have.

Call the `collectionViewContentSize` on your `aCollectionView.collectionViewLayout` property and get the height and width of the content in form of `CGSize`.

**OR**

```
-(CGFloat)collectionViewHeight
{
  [collectionView layoutIfNeeded];

  return [collectionView contentSize].height;
}
```

Comment: How does that get relayed to table view? Can you provide more details (i.e. code examples)?

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable for your height, and return that variable in your `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method. Then reload your tableView once you have figured out your height.

```
var height: CGFloat = 44

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return height
}

func something() {

    height = 1234//Or whatever your height should be
    self.table.reloadData()

}
```